# Form not being saved when specifying initial data

Tags: python, django

The following form doesn't get saved and I don't know why. The goal is just to get the initial data so the user doesn't have to enter it again, and upon completion of the form save it to the model.

views.py

```
class GetSellData(View):
    form_class = MakeSale
    template_name = 'laptops/laptop_sale.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Get post data from 'laptopname' button
        laptopid = request.POST.get('laptopname')
        #Store laptopid for use somewhere else
        request.session['laptopid'] = laptopid
        #get matching laptop id
        laptop = Laptop.objects.get(id=laptopid)
        #specify intital data based on laptop id for pre-populating the form
        data = {'Name': laptop.Name, 'specification': laptop.specification, 'warranty': laptop.warranty,'condition':laptop.condition}
        form = self.form_class(initial=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return render(request,'laptops/laptop_list.html')
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})'
```

Comment: It seems that you're asking for a request parameter called `laptopname` and then using this to look up the laptop by id. Is that right?

Comment: From the [documentation on `initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial): *These values are only displayed for unbound forms, and they’re not used as fallback values if a particular value isn’t provided.*

Comment: You are also not passing `request.POST` to your form when you initialise it, so any post data that was submitted will not be seen by the form.

Comment: .. .and as a result, the form is unbound, and is_valid will never be True.